# Create a new raster TIFF file which is masked based on the GeoJSON file

Tags: python, gdal, masking, rioxarray

I was trying to mask the building given its TIFF file and GeoJSON file  creating a new raster TIFF file. I don't know what is the problem, the result is all black, here is the code below:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

def create_building_mask(rasterSrc, vectorSrc, npDistFileName='', 
                        noDataValue=0, burn_values=1):

    source_ds = ogr.Open(vectorSrc)
    source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()


    srcRas_ds = gdal.Open(rasterSrc)
    cols = srcRas_ds.RasterXSize
    rows = srcRas_ds.RasterYSize


    memdrv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff') 
    dst_ds = memdrv.Create(npDistFileName, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(srcRas_ds.GetGeoTransform())
    dst_ds.SetProjection(srcRas_ds.GetProjection())
    band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    band.SetNoDataValue(noDataValue)    

    gdal.RasterizeLayer(dst_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[burn_values])

    dst_ds = 0

    return 

create_building_mask("img.tif", "img.geojson", npDistFileName='mask.tif', noDataValue=0, burn_values=1)
```

The result of mask.tif is all black, instead of masked img. [image]

Comment: You could try **gdal.RasterizeLayer(dst_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[burn_values], options='-init 0')** which should initialize the raster to 0 before burning in 1 for your buildings assuming that your *source_layer* has the same CRS as your template *srcRas_ds*.

Comment: You have created tiff that is of type Byte. If you use pixel value 1 for the masked area then it is pretty close to black for viewers which are showing the whole range 0-255 on screen. You can for example create mask image as 1 bit tiff, use pixel value 255 for a white mask, or do LUT stretch with your image viewer.

Comment: @user30184 I changed the' burn_bvalues' to 255 as you suggested, it worked. Thank you, your explanation made me clearly understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html) to do this type of operation. It uses [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) which is an alternative python wrapper for GDAL.

```py
import rioxarray
import json


# load in the geojson file
with open("img.geojson") as igj:
    data = json.load(igj)
# if GDAL 3+
crs = data["crs"]["properties"]["name"]
# crs = "EPSG:4326" # if GDAL 2
geoms = [feat["geometry"] for feat in data["features"]]

# create empty mask raster based on the input raster
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("img.tif").isel(band=0)
rds.values[:] = 1
rds.rio.write_nodata(0, inplace=True)

# clip the raster to the mask
clipped = rds.rio.clip(geoms, crs, drop=False)
```

[image]

```py
# or clip it inverted if that is what you wanted
clipped = rds.rio.clip(geoms, crs, drop=False, invert=True)
```

[image]

```py
# write output to file
clipped.rio.to_raster("mask.tif", dtype="uint8")
```

Alternatively, if you just want to mask out the buildings in the original tif file:

```py
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("img.tif")
clipped = rds.rio.clip(geoms, crs, drop=False, invert=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is really helpful.  I used your code, and I ploted the output using " input_img = plt.imread('mask.tif')  plt.imshow('input_img')", it showed masked result as expected, however if I open the "mask.tif" file itself, it is all black. And I noticed that the original "img.tif" has 'interleave': 'pixel' and the saved output file which is "mask.tif" has 'interleave': 'band', is that the reason why I open the 'mask.tif' file itself is all black? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could pass in `interleave="pixel"` into the `to_raster` function. What are you using to read in the file that shows it as all black?

Comment: I am using Preview to open the "mask.tif" file and it is all black, but I converted it to .png file. Problem solved. Many thanks .